# Web tab in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I wondering how I should go about the following:

What I'm looking to do is display a table of our data within a saleforce tab. The table data would be coming from a database that is in our shop. I also want to be able to pass data to the page (tab) to lookup information as I'm searching through the salesforce accounts.  Is this possible? If so what are some thoughts as to how to get this done?

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas.

1. You could do this by integrating the data from your local database with Salesforce. Here are some applications to make the integration process easier:

   - [Informatica](http://www.informatica.com/us/)
   - [CastIron](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/cast-iron-cloud-integration/salesforce-integration/)
   - [SnapLogic](http://www.snaplogic.com/)
   - [Boomi](http://www.boomi.com)
   - [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/)
2. Another option is to expose your data from your local database using webservices. Once you've done that, you can import (or [generate a class from](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm|SkinName=webhelp)) the webservice and consume it using Salesforce.

Getting the data is just the first step. If you use either option described above (integration or webservices), you will still need to develop a new Visualforce page and possibly an Apex Class (a custom [Visualforce Controller or Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm)) to display your data.

In addition, there may be other options using the new [Force.com REST API](http://developer.force.com/REST) or perhaps a Visualforce page with an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) that passes [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameters to the referenced page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt. So yesterday I wrote a little aspx page in ASP .Net and displayed that within a tab. Is there a way to pass Salesforce.com arguments to that? Is there a way to expose the page to take arguments? Sorry, I'm new to web development.

Comment: Usually, with an iframe (which is what a web tab is in Salesforce) the only way to pass arguments is by using querystring parameters, but I'm not seeing an option to pass querystring parameters to a web tab in Salesforce. I still think your best option is to integrate your data because that would be the fastest solution. If you're willing to use Visualforce, though, you could create a Visualforce page with an iframe (displaying your page) and then create a tab for that page. With this method, you won't need a custom controller or extension.

Comment: Alright sounds good. I'm going to have read up a little on using iframes to understand this more clearly. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Alright so I just read up on the iframe. I see that it imbeds the page with in the visualforce page, but I don't see a way to pass parameters to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: You would pass them in the iframe src URL with the structure mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: You're welcome! If your question is answered, please click the check mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!