# retrieving the data from salesforce

Tags: java, salesforce

We happened to get a requirement - we are supposed to sync the data between salesforce and our database in designated intervals of time.

The synchronization will happen based on some criteria

1. Fetch the salesforce data using "Business id".
2. Sync it with the database.

I'm looking for options here considering performance ( we can load the salesforce data in batches ) . We are looking into the various resources like

```
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm
http://blog.teamlazerbeez.com/2009/05/06/salesforcecom-api-gotchas-1/
```

Can you shed some light on this providing some more useful resources and the direction how to proceed ( we will be using SOAP using Java to interact with salesforce)

Comment: I believe I did enough research and I dont have enough experience with salesforce which is the reason , I posted the question here . May be this isnt the reason to downvote ??

Comment: I'm not sure why your question was down-voted, but check out these options for integration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328212/web-tab-in-salesforce/8332980#8332980.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tolerado framework for Java(SOAP) integration with Salesforce. More details here : http://code.google.com/p/tolerado-sfdc-wsc-apis/

Comment: these resources are really useful . If we would like to retrieve the data in batches , do we really need to use bulk API's . Cant we use queryMore . I'm not sure if they both are almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [CopyForce](http://code.google.com/p/sqlforce/wiki/CopyForce) tool.

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh . I will take a look .If we would like to retrieve the data in batches , do we really need to use bulk API's . Cant we use queryMore . I'm not sure if they both are almost the same