# Getting started with integration

Tags: salesforce

I'm a web developer and I want to integrate a project of mine with salesforce.com. There is a tremendous amount of documentation on the salesforce.com site, but I can't figure out where and how to start.

- I want to display part of the existing UI (HTML5) in a sf.com tab.
- The functionality of this extra tab will need to access contacts etc. entered in sf.com.

What's the best strategy to do this? Is there a document/blog somewhere to get me started?

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? What language is it written in? Will all of the interaction be in SalesForce, or on an external site that pulls data from SalesForce?  Setting up an app and a tab in SalesForce requires that you either write a page in Apex, or use an iFrame.  I can help you further, but just need more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an external web page within Salesforce, it's possible to set up a "Web Tab" in Salesforce (Setup | App Setup | Create | Tabs). However, if you want to access Salesforce data with-in the web page in the Web Tab, I would recommend creating a Visualforce Page with an iFrame in it, instead. Using that method, you can pass querystring parameters like the Session ID for the current user, or other data.

To access data from the page in the Visualforce page iFrame or web tab, you would need to use one of the APIs Salesforce makes available such as:

- [Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm)
- [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_CSH.htm#intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)
- [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm)

For more information on this type of integration, see this [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328212/web-tab-in-salesforce).

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me to an example with the iFrame method, passing data as querystring parameters?

Comment: <iframe src="yourpage.html?sessionid={!$Api.Session_ID}" /> That or something similar should do it.